# speeding up dataframe column assignment with lambdas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, dataframe

Is there some way i can apply a lambda function to all members of the list **columns** in order to speed the following up?  Thanks!

```
for column in columns:
    table_name, column_name = column.split('|')
    df.loc[:, column] = df.apply(lambda r: fn(r), axis=1)
```

Comment: the bottleneck of your code probably isn't iterating over the columns, it's iterating over the **rows**, can you post the code of your `fn`, and maybe we can help you rewrite it using faster vectorised operations?

Comment: You need to post what your lambda is trying to do, also this `table_name, column_name = column.split('|')` seems irrelevant to your question